# Referenciação de um elemento específico de uma matriz bidemensional via a notação de ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

O C permite tratar cada linha de uma matriz de duas dimensões as considerando como uma matriz de uma dimensão.

Como conhecido, uma maneira de referenciarmos matrizes bidimensionais na forma de ponteiros em C é, por exemplo:

```
tabela[j][k] = *(*(tabela + j) + k)
```

De acordo com meu livro a apostilas:

Vamos assumir que o endereço da matriz tabela seja 1000, então
tabela == 1000 e que tabela seja uma matriz [4][5]

Como tabela é uma matriz inteira, cada elemento ocupa neste caso 4 bytes. Temos 5 elementos em cada linha, então cada linha ocupa 20 bytes. Como cada linha é uma matriz de uma dimensão, cada matriz de uma dimensão começa 20 bytes após a anterior

Portanto, 
tabela + 1
toma o endereço de tabela (1000) e adiciona o número de bytes da linha (5 colunas vezes 4 bytes por coluna, resultando 20 bytes)

Então, tabela + 1 é interpretado como o endereço 1020, que é o endereço da segunda matriz de uma dimensão da matriz, tabela + 2 é o endereço da terceira e assim por diante

Como referenciar um elemento individual na linha?

O endereço da matriz é o mesmo que o endereço do primeiro elemento da matriz. Já está determina2do que o endereço da matriz formada pela terceira linha é tabela[2] ou tabela+2 em notação de ponteiro.

O endereço do primeiro elemento desta matriz formada pela terceira linha é &tabela[2][0] ou *(tabela + 2) em notação de ponteiro. Logo, tabela + 2 e *(tabela + 2) referenciariam o mesmo endereço, no caso, 1040.

Entretanto, pelo que conheço de ponteiros, o operador *, de deferência, devolve o conteúdo de um endereço apontado. Considerando que tabela+2 é um endereço, logo *(tabela + 2) deveria me retornar o conteúdo/valor para o qual este endereço aponta, e não 1040.

Logo, tecnicamente, a expressão

```
tabela[j][k] = *(*(tabela + j) + k)
```

não faria sentido, pois *(tabela + j) deveria me retornar um valor, e não um endereço.

Minha dúvida é o porque as expressões tabela + 2 e *(tabela + 2) referenciariam o mesmo endereço, sendo que a primeira deveria retornar um endereço e a segunda o valor deste endereço

Comment: Mas a sua questão é sobre perceber como os ponteiros funcionam em matrizes bidimensionais ? Pois obter valores numa matriz bidimensional é bem simples utilizando notação de array através dos indices com `matriz[i][j]`. E o mesmo para o endereço de qualquer elemento da matriz com `&matriz[i][j]`.

Comment: O meu questionamento se baseia em entender como funciona a referenciação de um elemento específico de uma matriz bidemensional via a notação de ponteiro, que é

    tabela[j][k] = *(*(tabela + j) + k)

porque 

*(tabela + j)

pelas notações de ponteiro me retornaria um valor, e não um endereço

Comment: O erro está na sua interpretação de `*(tabela + j)`. O tipo devolvido por isso é `int*` e não `int` como você assumiu, pois uma matriz 2d funciona como se fosse um ponteiro de ponteiros, embora na prática não o seja.

Comment: Então significa que *(tabela + j) me devolve um ponteiro int * que aponta para o endereço da linha j em questão?

Comment: comentário do @Isac está correto...a declaração `int tabela[4][5]` é interpretada sintaticamente como um array de 4 elementos, onde cada elemento é o ponteiro para um array de 5 ints...a expressão `tabela[2]` é interpretada como sendo o ponteiro para o terceiro array de 5 ints...na prática, o uso de arrays bi-dimensionais (e multi-dimensionais)  em C é muito reduzido,  o normal é trabalhar com arrays de ponteiros,,,não sei por que os professores insistem nesse negócio de "matriz" em C...

Comment: a expressão `*(tabela + j)` é a mesma coisa que `tabela[j]`, que *por definição* é um ponteiro para a "linha" de índice j

Comment: Sim, a minha dificuldade fica em entender o porque `*(tabela + j)` me devolve o endereço da linha j / do 1º elemento da linha j (no caso 1040) e não o conteúdo deste mesmo elemento (que seria algum número inteiro, por exemplo 30)
Já que quando estudo ponteiros tenho por base que * é um operador de deferência que me retornar o conteúdo/valor localizado no endereço (ponteiro) operando
Assim, acreditei que `*(tabela + j)` me devolveria o valor/conteúdo do primeiro elemento da linha j cujo endereço é `tabela + j`
Acredito que a diferença esteja no tratamento com matrizes bidimensionais

Comment: Ai fica a dificuldade de compreender a notação em ponteiros para ponteiros

Comment: "por base que * é um operador de deferência que me retornar o conteúdo/valor localizado no endereço (ponteiro)" - Sim e por isso se você desreferencia um `int**` fica com um `int*` (um ponteiro) e não um `int` (numero). O **conteudo** de `tabela + j` é um **ponteiro e não um `int`**.